# Abelian Variety and Tangent Bundle ----Reference Request

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, textbook-recommendation

I am looking for the reference where I can find the proof of the following:

If $A$ is an abelian variety then its tangent bundle is trivial.

Comment: This of course is a general fact for algebraic groups and there are references for that. However, a reference for abelian varieties is given by David Mumford: Abelian varieties, Ch 4 (iii)

Comment: i suggest you first try as an exercise to think of an interesting map from AxV to TA where A is an abelian variety and V the tangent space at the origin, and TA is the tangent bundle.

Comment: Another interesting reference is the first two sections of chapter 4 in Néron Models by Bosch, Lütkebohmert and Raynaud.

Comment: This question just got bumped to the front-page by MathOverflow. @yuvi, can you accept the answer below so it'll get registered as solved by the software. Since this was already on the front-page I retagged as textbook-recommendation since this fact you seek is discussed in many textbooks and effectively you're asking which is best. For my money, Torsten's answer is the most useful such text. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See also

http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/notes_bremen.ps

which proves a converse (corr. 2.3)

Comment: However, the converse is false in positive characteristic: Igusa has given an example of a variety with trivial tangent bundle in characteristic $2$ that is not an Abelian variety: it arises as $(E\times E')/({\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, where $E$ and $E'$ are elliptic curves, and the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts via sign involution on one factor and via translation of a $2$-torsion point on the other factor.

Comment: The paper "essentially finite vector bundles on varieties with trivial vector bundle" (by Biswas, Parameswaran, Subramanian) says more about what happens in positive characteristic.