# Must an algebraic variety with trivial tangent bundle be an abelian variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a proper algebraic variety with trivial tangent bundle $T_X$ (not only canonical bundle $K_X$), is it true that $X$ is an abelian variety?

I think the holomorphic tangent bundle of a Hopf surface will not be trivial, according to the comment below..

Comment: There's probably a more low-tech way to do this, but such a manifold is a Kahler manifold with trivial canonical bundle and thus has a finite cover that splits into a product of tori, hyperkahler and Calabi-Yau manifolds. Since it has a trivial canonical bundle there's only a torus factor in the cover, which is an abelian variety because it has a finite quotient that is projective. So up to finite quotients, yes.

Comment: Yes, assuming the variety is a complex projective manifold. (Prove that the assumption implies that the Albanese map $X \to \mathbb{Alb}(X)$ is etale.) No in positive characteristic. For examples, see Mehta and Srinivas, "Varieties in positive characteristic with trivial tangent bundle," *Compositio Math.*, 1987.

Comment: And no if you don't assume some properness condition.

Comment: ...since any affine algebraic group gives an example.

Comment: Does the Hopf manifold really have trivial tangent bundle? The sections $zd/dz, wd/dz, zd/dw, wd/dw$ on $\mathbb C^2$ are scale-invariant and so descend to the Hopf surface. But the structure sheaf of the Hopf surface has a 1-dimensional space of sections, so a trivial rank two vector bundle should have a $2$-dimensional space of sections. But there is no linear relation among these.

Comment: mqx: you should erase your parenthetical second sentence since it is false,  as explained by  @Will's crystal-clear  argument ( which moreover you seem to acknowledge in your third sentence!)

Comment: I'm clearly missing something, but doesn't trivial canonical (cotangent?) bundle imply trivial tangent bundle? Isn't the dual of a free sheaf itself free?

Comment: @oxeimon canonical is the top exterior power.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/73846

Answer (score 28, accepted):

More generally, in the complex case the following result holds.

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold which is complex parallelisable, i.e.  such that 
>   $T_X$ is holomorphically trivial. Then $X$ is a complex torus. In particular, if $X$ is algebraic then $X$ is an abelian variety.

For the proof, see

H. C. Wang: *[Complex parallisable manifolds](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1954-005-05/S0002-9939-1954-0074064-3/home.html)*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **5** (1954), 771–776.

Comment: What a beautiful theorem.